# Locating timessteps with a non-succesive value

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a very long timeseries indicating wether a day was dry (no rain) or wet. Part of the timeserie is shown here:

```
Date          DryDay  
2009-05-07    0    
2009-05-08    0  
2009-05-09    1  
2009-05-10    1  
2009-05-11    1  
2009-05-12    1  
2009-05-13    1
2009-05-14    0
2009-05-15    0
2009-05-16    0
2009-05-17    0
2009-05-18    1
2009-05-20    0
2009-05-21    1
2009-05-22    0
2009-05-23    1
2009-05-24    1
2009-05-25    1
2009-05-26    0
2009-05-27    0
2009-05-28    1
2009-05-29    1
2009-05-30    0
....
```

I need to find dry periods, which means that I want to find periods with succesive dry days (more than one dry days succesive). Therefore I would like change the value of *DryDay* from 1 to 0 when there is only on dry day succesive. Like this:

```
Date          DryDay  
2009-05-07    0    
2009-05-08    0  
2009-05-09    1  
2009-05-10    1  
2009-05-11    1  
2009-05-12    1  
2009-05-13    1
2009-05-14    0
2009-05-15    0
2009-05-16    0
2009-05-17    0
2009-05-18    0
2009-05-20    0
2009-05-21    0
2009-05-22    0
2009-05-23    1
2009-05-24    1
2009-05-25    1
2009-05-26    0
2009-05-27    0
2009-05-28    1
2009-05-29    1
2009-05-30    0
...
```

Can anyone help me how to do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way but here is one,

```
df['DryDay'] = ((df['DryDay'] == 1) & ((df['DryDay'].shift() == 1) | (df['DryDay'].shift(-1) == 1))).astype(int)

    Date        DryDay
0   2009-05-07  0
1   2009-05-08  0
2   2009-05-09  1
3   2009-05-10  1
4   2009-05-11  1
5   2009-05-12  1
6   2009-05-13  1
7   2009-05-14  0
8   2009-05-15  0
9   2009-05-16  0
10  2009-05-17  0
11  2009-05-18  0
12  2009-05-20  0
13  2009-05-21  0
14  2009-05-22  0
15  2009-05-23  1
16  2009-05-24  1
17  2009-05-25  1
18  2009-05-26  0
19  2009-05-27  0
20  2009-05-28  1
21  2009-05-29  1
22  2009-05-30  0
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
((df1.DryDay.rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum()>1)|(df1.DryDay.iloc[::-1].rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum()>1)).astype(int)
Out[95]: 
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    1
16    1
17    1
18    0
19    0
20    1
21    1
22    0
Name: DryDay, dtype: int32
```